# Aborting commit due to empty commit message, using VS Code as Git editor

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

So I've tried to make VS Code my Git editor by using this `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`, and so far it is working ok until the moment I want to make a commit. Once i do  `git commit` command, a blank new "file" opens up in VS code, waiting for me to name the commit, I just write a simple message, **save it** and close the tab (by pressing `ctrl+w` or by clicking on the **x**) at which point I get this message **Aborting commit due to empty commit message.**

The funny thing is that everything works fine if I do `git commit --amend`.

Just some information for all, I am using VS Code on Windows, I installed git and also use WSL(Ubuntu) terminal.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, are you explicitly saving the the contents of the commit message before you close the tab? If you're not, that might explain why Git is complaining about the absence of a message.

Comment: @miqh gave the answer : git opens an editor because he actually expects you to *write the commit message to a file*. From the editor, you need to save the content to disk (`Ctrl + S`)

Comment: yeah, I am saving the the contents. I have used this VS Code before in such a way, while working on mac or linux and it worked fine, but now I am using windows and this problem is happening and I don't know why.

Comment: ok. Do you run your `git commit` command from a WSL shell ?

Comment: I don't know if it is the same thing but it is called Ubuntu (WSL) in my VS Code. I use my git command here

Answer (score 1):

Close VSCode and then type again `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was picking not to save and that caused the issue.
I select to save and now commit worked.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write the same question. I'm new here btw. But I thought about the process of adding editor to git settings. I got a flash. I just psted this problem on yt and I got it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B27pUBrWp5w

THIS ----

```
[core]
    editor = "code -nw"
```

----<<<
You must paste to your git user config setting. For global git settings is in C:\Users(Your User Name).gitconfig

Just add the -nw tag like abowe. Make sure to not forget the apostrophe.
I'm a genius :D

Comment: PS: Probably command >>>> git config --global core.editor "code --nw" <<<<<< should works too.